# AngularJS data binding not working with `<div>` appended to DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Here's my code to help understand my problem:

```
var app = angular.module('myProfile', []);

app.controller('myWrapperCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.fetchData = function() {
    $http.post('/rankData', { id: $('h2.name').attr('id')}).then(function(response) {
        $scope.data = response.data;

        var newElement = angular.element('<div class="myRanks">{{data}}</div>');
        var target = document.getElementsByTagName('body');

        if ($('.myRanks').length === 0) {
            angular.element(target).append(newElement);
        }
    });




};
}]);
```

In the above code I basically create a div and assign the variable *data*, which later on will be filled with data I fetch from a post request.

```
<button type="button" id="ranks" ng-click="fetchData()">Ranks</button>
```

In my ejs file I have set up a simple process where when I press a button *fetchData()* gets called which as I mentioned creates a div with supposedly data from the post request which in this case it doesn't. It just prints out {{data}} instead of the data from the post request.

For further clarification I've posted a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqOG8.png) that shows the problem in a more visual sense.

One solution I've come to find is that instead of `'<div class="myRanks">{{data}}</div>` I put the variable between the strings, like so `'<div class="myRanks">' + $scope.data + '</div>`, but that prevents me from controlling the variable from the ejs file and the usage of directives like *ng-repeat*.

Comment: What if you make the `<div>` exist from the start? Setting `$scope.data` should auto-fill it. `angular.element` apparently takes raw HTML, and double curly brackets are used as-is.

Comment: Avoid doing DOM manipulation in AngularJS controllers. DOM manipulation should be done either with [built-in directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive) or [custom directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the following in your html:

```
<div class="myRanks" ng-hide = "data == null" >{{data}}</div>
```

The div won't show up until you have `data` populated.

Comment: This works perfectly. Seems like my lack of angularjs knowledge was to blame here. Thanks

Comment: @RichardKasendu Awesome. Can you please accept my answer. It would help me. Thanks